# How to generate a private recipe JSON from the contents of a recipe directory?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-flex

I've developed a Symfony bundle, and I am trying to create a recipe.  Before submitting it to `recipes-contrib`, I want to test it, so I followed [the instructions for private recipes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex_private_recipes.html) -- not because I want a private recipe (that is, neither the bundle nor the recipe is "private" in the sense of a private GitHub project).

I have read, re-read, then read again the documentation for creating a recipe, and I feel like I'm missing a very important step.  The documentation for a private repository only talks about the package.version.json file, e.g.

```json
{
    "manifests": {
        "acme/private-bundle": {
            "manifest": {
                "bundles": {
                    "Acme\\PrivateBundle\\AcmePrivateBundle": [
                        "all"
                    ]
                },
                "copy-from-recipe": {
                    "config/": "%CONFIG_DIR%"
                }
            },
            "files": {
                "config/packages/acme_private.yaml": {
                    "contents": [
                        "acme_private:",
                        "    encode: true",
                        ""
                    ],
                    "executable": false
                }
            },
            "ref": "7405f3af1312d1f9121afed4dddef636c6c7ff00"
        }
    }
}
```

This file appears to be the output of some command that reads the file in the format as expected for a `contrib` recipe: a directory structure that has a `config` directory for routes and packages, maybe a `src` directory, etc.

Obviously, no one is typing in by hand line by line a YAML file (or PHP!) as a list of strings in the `content` key.

It appears that the `master` branch of recipes and `recipes-contrib` contains the directory structure, and `flex/main` branch contains the "compiled" JSON recipe file.

But in the private recipe instructions, there are no instructions as to how to get from the DX-friendly files to the JSON recipe.

TL;DR; How do I create a `package.version.json` recipe from the package/version/ directory that contains `manifest.json`, `config`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem few hours ago and I finally get it.
Clues were given by the blog post https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-flex-is-going-serverless were we can see that a script and a tool exist.

I duplicated the Github Actions and adapted those files in one of my repositories: https://github.com/web-token/recipes

- The `main` branch contains the compiled files, including the `index.json`: **this is what you want to have to get it working**.
- The `tree` branch is the one where developer friendly files live.

The `tree` branch contains the Github Actions workflows that update the `main` branch.
Feel free to copy and adapt the folder https://github.com/web-token/recipes/tree/tree/.github with your parameters.

Note that the server URL to declare in the composer file will look like `https://api.github.com/repos/web-token/recipes/contents/index.json?ref=main`

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking. I believe they are asking how to generate `web-token.jwt-framework.3.0.json` without having to write the JSON file by hand. Note the _"Obviously no one is typing in by hand line by line a yaml file (or PHP!) as a list of strings in the "content" key"_ remark.

Comment: Your are right. I modified my answer after I realized that this is quite simple (just a fex Github specific files).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I agree that the instructions are a big opaque there.

The missing step is performed by by `symfony-tools/recipe-checker` ([link](https://github.com/symfony-tools/recipes-checker)).

The repo is (sadly) not available as a package on Packagist, so to install and run it locally you'd it you either modify your configuration to add a custom repository pointing there, or you clone/download without using composer.

E.g.

```
git clone https://github.com/symfony-tools/recipes-checker
cd recipes-checker
composer install
```

Now you have the script ready to use.
Assuming you downloaded it in your home directory, you could run:

```
~/recipe-checker/run generate:flex-endpoint <repository> <source_branch> <flex_branch> <output_directory>
```

The different arguments are (as gotten from `run generate:flex-endpoint --help`):

```
Arguments:
  repository            The name of the GitHub repository
  source_branch         The source branch of recipes
  flex_branch           The branch of the target Flex endpoint
  output_directory      The directory where generated files should be stored
  versions_json         The file where versions of Symfony are described
```

So if you have a recipe repository for a package like `yivi/stub-bundle`, version 1.0, with the repository hosted at https://github.com/yivi/stub-bundle-recipe

```
<dir>
└── yivi
     └─stub-bundle
          └── 1.0
               ├── bin
               │   └── something.sh
               ├ manifest.json
               └ post-install.json
```

You could simply `cd` into the package directory and run:

```
~/recipe-checker/run generate:flex-endpoint yivi/stub-bundle-recipe main main .
```

This would generate locally the "compiled" recipe (or recipes, if you have multiple on that directory) and you'd end up with this in that directory:

- `index.json`
- `yivi.stub-bundle.1.0.json`
- `archived/` (dir)

To "test" this locally, it would simply a matter to commit and push this repo, and on a project that will want to use the recipes hosted here update the `composer.json` `extra.symfony` field to include:

```json
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
       "endpoint": [
           "https://api.github.com/repos/yivi/stub-bundle-recipe/contents/index.json",
           "flex://defaults"
            ]
        }
}
```

The [nice answer by Spomky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71693141/1426539) links to a GitHub action that could do this for you automatically on the receiving repo, cleanly separating in different branches the "source" recipes and the "compiled" recipes, but I think this example will more easily show how to perform the process step by step by yourself.